# Why width isnt increasing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to increase width of progress bar on click of button.

https://codepen.io/Gotlib/pen/BdLNLy

```
var a = 0;
var bonus = a + "px";
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".but").click(function(){  
     document.getElementById('lone').style.width=parseInt("bonus", 10)+ "px";
     a+=10; 
  });
});
```

Comment: `parseInt("bonus"` == `NaN` - even if you change that to `parseInt(bonus` - you never change `bonus` anyway, only `a` - javascript wont retrospectively change `bonus` when you change `a`

Comment: Andrew Gotlib  check the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First - you probably should use `parseInt(bonus, 10)` instead of `parseInt("bonus", 10)`.

And why use `bonus` var in first place? You can do this with one variable:

```js
var a = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".but").click(function() {
    document.getElementById("lone").style.width = a + "px";
    a += 10;
  });
});
```

```css
.but {
    background-color: green; 
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.for{
  display: flex;
  justify-content:center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>The pgrogress</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" id="lone" role="progressbar" style="width: 0" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
</div>
 <div class="for">
   <button class="but">Button</button>
  </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

`parseInt("bonus", 10)` will return a `NaN`. So use `parseInt(bonus, 10)` for the result.

But the thing is that you are not changing the value of bonus on click.

So the right way is to use `parseInt(a, 10)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help:

```
var a = 0;
var bonus = a;
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".but").click(function(){  document.getElementById('lone').style.width=parseInt(a+10)+'%';
         a+=10; 
  });

});
```

```js
var a = 0;
var bonus = a;
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".but").click(function(){  document.getElementById('lone').style.width=parseInt(a+10)+'%';
         a+=10; 
  });
  
});
```

```css
.but {
    background-color: green; 
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.for{
  display: flex;
  justify-content:center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>The pgrogress</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" id="lone" role="progressbar" style="width: 5%" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
</div>
 <div class="for">
   <button class="but">Button</button>
  </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Update your javascript function with this.

```
var CurrentValue =  $('#lone').width();
var incremental = 10;
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".but").click(function(){
    $('#lone').width(CurrentValue += incremental);
  }); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You only need to apply the [parseInt()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp) function in order to remove the "px" at the end of the value.

I also slightly simplified the jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  a = parseInt($('#lone').css('width'));

  $(".but").click(function(){  
    a+=10;
    $('#lone').css('width', a + 'px');
  });

});
```

Here's a [CodePen fork with changes applied](https://codepen.io/rogersegu/pen/brWeWG).

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Just update your Codepan "js" by this below code and i hope you also want like this.

```
var a = 0;
var bonus = a + "px";
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".but").click(function(){  
         a+=10; 
      $('.progress-bar').css('width',a)
  });

});
```